# Approximation of a function and second derivative

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, approximation

While solving some exercise I came up with this problem:

> Assume that $f \in C^2[0,\infty]$ (i.e. $f$ has continuous second derivative on $[0,\infty)$ and there exists limit in $+\infty$ of $f$) be such that $f''(0) = 0$.
>
> Does there exist a sequence $(f_n) \subset C^2[0,\infty]$ such that $f_n \to f$ and $f''_n \to f''$ in the supremum norm (i.e. $\lVert f_n - f \rVert_{C[0,\infty]}$, $ \lVert f''_n - f'' \rVert_{C[0,\infty]} \to 0$ ) and all $f_n$'s satisfies $f''_n(0) = f'_n(0) = 0$?

Maybe I am wrong but I think it would be nearly enough to approximate in that sense linear (in some neighborhood of $0$) functions.

I will be grateful  for any hints.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible. Assume $f(x) = x$ for $ x \le 1$, suitably extended for $x\ge 1$. Now choose $\varepsilon$ small (less than $1/100$, say) and $N_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|f(x) - f_n(x) | \le \varepsilon, |f^{\prime \prime}(x) - f_n^{\prime \prime}(x)| \le \varepsilon \quad \forall x\in \mathbb{R}, n\ge N_0$.

Your assumption ($f_n^{\prime}(0) = 0$) then implies

$$|f_n^{\prime}(x)| = |\int_0^x f_n^{\prime\prime}(t) dt| = |\int_0^x (f_n^{\prime\prime} (t) - f^{\prime\prime}(t) ) dt|\le \varepsilon x \quad \forall x\ge 0 \quad (!)$$ 
since $f^{\prime\prime} = 0$. This allows you to estimate $f_n(0) - f_n(x)$ (integrate once more). Hence 
$$\varepsilon \ge f(x) - f_n(x) = f(x) - f(0) + f(0) - f_n(0)  + f_n(0) - f_n(x) \ge x - \varepsilon -(\varepsilon/2) |x|^2 $$
Now choose $x = 1/2$, say.

Comment: Thanks! Really nice. As I thought, linear functions were crucial.